# Directory Clean Up

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python coming from Ruby on Rails. I am building a cleanup script for cleaning (archiving, deleting, or viewing) directories.  I would love to know anything that I can make better, safer, faster.

```
import os
import re
import shutil
import argparse
from datetime import datetime

# Example: python cleanup.py -d u:\jobs -p u:\jobs\pattern_file.txt -r list
"""
Example pattern file:

template
^\d{5,}
twin

"""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', type=str, default="pattern_file.txt", help="Pattern File (One item per line, regex or string)")
parser.add_argument('-d', help='Directory to clean up.')
parser.add_argument('-a', help='Minimum number of days old to clean up.')
parser.add_argument('-r', type=str, help='delete, archive or test.')
args = parser.parse_args()


def included_files(directory, pattern_file, age_string = 90):
    """ Find files to move """
    all_files = []
    excluded_files = []

    os.chdir(directory)

    patterns = fix_pattern(pattern_file)
    for fname in os.listdir(directory):
        all_files.append(fname)

        for pattern in patterns:

            # Check for matching pattern in filename
            if re.search(pattern, fname.lower()):  # Regex search
                excluded_files.append(fname)

        # Check to see if the difference in today and modified date is more than "age"
        now = datetime.now()
        then = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fname))
        tdelta = now - then
        if type(age_string) == str:
            age = int(age_string)
        else:
            age = 90
        if tdelta.days < age:
            excluded_files.append(fname)
    value = [x for x in all_files if x not in excluded_files]
    return value


def file_maintenance(dir_path, files, type):
    """ File Maintenance """
    if os.path.isdir(dir_path):
        directory = dir_path
    else:
        directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    archive_directory = os.path.join(directory.strip(), 'archive', "")

    for file in files:
        if os.path.isdir(file) is not True:
            if type is "archive":
                if os.path.isdir(archive_directory) is not True:
                    os.makedirs(archive_directory)
                print("Moving " + os.path.join(directory, file) + " to " + os.path.join(archive_directory, file))
                shutil.move(os.path.join(directory, file), os.path.join(archive_directory, file))
            elif type is "delete":
                print('Deleting ' + os.path.join(directory, file))
                os.remove(file)
            else:
                print("File: " + os.path.join(directory, file))


def fix_pattern(pattern_file):
    if os.path.isfile(pattern_file):
        print("pattern file found")
        with open(pattern_file) as f:
            content = f.readlines()
        pattern = [x.strip() for x in content]

    else:
        print("pattern file not found")
        pattern = []        
    pattern.append('pattern_file')
    return pattern


if __name__ == "__main__":

    files = included_files(args.d, args.p, args.a)
    file_maintenance(args.d, files, args.r)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following:

- Use PyCharm or IntelliJ IDEA with the Python plugin. Either will detect several of the following issues, and you can simply cycle through them using <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Put the argument parsing inside a function. It's clearer and you avoid issues with importing your stuff from other code.
- Run the code through `pycodestyle` to discover several issues such as `foo is not True` which should be `not foo`.
- Use long name options such as `--pattern-file` to make your options obvious to a new user.
- Always treat `age_string` as an `int`. This means setting the ArgumentParser argument type, renaming the parameter and removing all the `if type(age_string) == str` stuff.
- Inline the `value` variable - it's only used once, and that in a trivial manner.
- Use a single list rather than adding all the files to a list, then creating a list of exclusions, then subtracting one from the other. Do all the checks and `continue` the loop if any of them apply to the file under consideration.
- Create constants for any magic values, for example `archive` and `90`.
- Understand why the string `pattern_file` is added to the pattern list, and most likely remove it.
- Make it obvious (in the code, not just the argument help text) that the patterns are lists of *exclusions.*
- In general, don't try to second guess the user's intentions. For example, it should be an error if you have a `dir_path` parameter which does not point to an existing directory. If it points to a file then the user has misunderstood how to use it.

Comment: While I agree with most of your points, I think relying on an IDE to find and fix errors for you isn't going to help you improve your coding skills as a whole.

Comment: I think you might have misread my answer, as "relying on" is nowhere to be found in it.

Comment: As I don't feel like creating a new answer for such minor points, two additions related to `argparse` that you could mention: use `default=90` for the `-a` option and use `choices=...` (or a subcommand) for the `-r` option.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and ideas.  This is the first time I have found code review, so also thanks for the great first experience!